# Different backgrounds, clipped to paths in a figure?

Tags: graphics

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287444/latex-used-to-draw-this-figure) there is this image:

[image]

Is there a way to create such backgrounds? It doesn't have to be a LaTeX native method, hopefully open source. A library of backgrounds usable would be a nice addition.

**Added later:** I didn't mean backgrounds created with the mentioned tools, necessarily. A place where I can get backgrounds to cut as backgrounds was the idea.

Comment: Why the specific tag `asymptote`? I don't think the tag applies here.

Comment: @Alenanno, because it is the general-purpose drawing package I most use.

Comment: Ok, but tags are supposed to describe the question. Nothing in this question is related to `asymptote`. `tikz-pgf` would be the tag if you really want one. Or none, if you want to allow various solutions.

Comment: In any case +1, it's an interesting question.

Comment: @Alenanno, TikZ is LaTeX native, asymptote is an external program that happens to work extremely well with LaTeX.

Comment: if you are not asking to generate the backgrounds in tex as clarified  in your edit I think you are just asking for a resource for textures so clearly off topic here and should be asked perhaps on the graphic design site.

Comment: Google "background pattern graphics" and steal what you need.  Tikz can do both cropping and moving to the background layer.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't drawn your arrows and other lines - you can do that yourself. These are example textures from the tcolorbox package (use your own textures)

Depending on the type of images you are using as background you can use either

fill overzoom image, fill stretch image=image, fill tile image*={height=3cm}{image} (latter an image that is a repeating tile)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fill overzoom image=blueshade] (0,0) rectangle +(2,3);

\fill[fill overzoom image=blueshade] (2,0) rectangle +(1,3);

\fill[fill overzoom image=goldshade] (3,0) rectangle +(6,1.5);
\fill[fill overzoom image=blueshade] (9,0) rectangle +(4,1.5);
\fill[fill overzoom image=goldshade] (3,1.5) rectangle +(10,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another example showing different types of stretches and tiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fill overzoom image=blueshade] (0,0) rectangle +(2,3);

\fill[fill stretch image=goldshade] (2,0) rectangle +(1,3);

\fill[fill stretch image=goldshade] (3,0) rectangle +(6,1.5);
\fill[fill tile image*={height=3cm}{crinklepaper.png}] (9,0) rectangle +(4,1.5);
\fill[fill tile image*={height=3cm}{pink_marble.png}] (3,1.5) rectangle +(10,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's the top-right pattern. Not quite the same thing, but it would require more controls to achieve a more similar result.

Also, I strongly advise **not** to use this, because it places a huge load on the compiling process and also on the final file. Just for comparison, a simple diagram like the one in the OP (without the backgrounds) generates a  4 KB .pdf file. This one is *507 KB*.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, fadings}

\tikzfading[name=to bottom,
    top color=transparent!0,
    bottom color=transparent!100]

\tikzfading[name=fade out,
    inner color=transparent!0,
    outer color=transparent!100]

\newcommand\drop[2]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#2)},scale=#1]
    \fill[cyan, path fading=to bottom] (0,0) coordinate (s) to[out=96,in=86, looseness=4] coordinate (w) (1,0) coordinate (e);
    \fill[white, path fading=fade out] ($(s)!.5!(w)+(-1mm,0)$) to[out=90,in=120] ($(e)!.75!(w)+(0,1mm)$)  to[out=190,in=30] cycle;
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-9,-3) rectangle (9,3);

\foreach \x in {-9,-8.6,...,9}{%
\foreach \y in {-3,-2.6,...,3}{
    \pgfmathparse{rand}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\temp{(\pgfmathresult*10)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tempp{\ifnum\temp<0 -\temp\else\temp\fi}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\scale{\ifnum\tempp=0 \tempp+1\else\tempp\fi}
    \drop{0.\scale}{\x,\y}
    }
}
\fill[cyan, fill opacity=.35] (-9,-3) rectangle (9,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. We seem to have two different interpretations of what the question is. Your answer is a lot of fun but creating textures in tikz seems overkill when there are zillions out there.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I interpreted is as vonbrand was asking how to create the actual backgrounds, when he said "Is there a way to create such backgrounds?"... Of course, there are better ways, and I wouldn't use this. This was just an exercise, so to speak. :D

Comment: No, I didn't want to create the backgrounds, just being able to swizzle a snippet of some nice ones.  Thanks (+1) anyway, and I can see you enjoyed it.

Comment: Very impressive example of What Ought Not Be Done with TikZ.